# Joomla restricted pages are redirected to 301 Moved Permanently after HTTPS redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess-configuration, joomla-1.5, apache, https

I have Joomla site with a load balancer (AWS). The website is redirected to https, after redirecting home page works correctly. However, on restricted pages after login are giving the error
*301 Moved Permanently* in developer tools and the login fails.

When I `force_ssl='2'` it goes into a redirect loop. So i have used .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Required help as I am stucked and need to resolve ASAP.